# write out of a python program execute through bash

Tags: bash, python-2.7, embedded-linux

I have a little python tool useable in bash command, on a embedded linux (on a seismic digitizer). In my example, that's the tool which call the sensors (in this case, voltage sensors) then out the results in the terminal.
The tool is just 3 lines of script that call a library:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
from ccube.apps.ccube_sensors import main
sys.exit(main())
```

I really don't know what is "ccube.apps.ccube_sensors".
Nevermind, I just want the print result in bash to be inject in a txt file, but doing a ">" doesn't work.

Here the use of the tool :

```
/usr/bin/ccube-sensors voltage -m all > test.log
```

(-m is or "machine" format out, "all" is all sensors)

in the terminal, it produce :

```
system=12.60V battery=3.25V
```

But test.log still empty.
Notice : the digitizer run a old 2.7 python and this is a arm proc device with a unknow embedded linux.

Comment: From your description, I conclude that your program either writes to the terminal (i.e. what your shell shows when you do a `echo $TTY`), or that it writes to stderr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your Python abuses the `sys.exit()` function to print its output. As a result, it prints the string it receives as a parameter on `stderr` and exits with a non-successful error status. As a result of writing on `stderr`, rather than `stdout`, the messages are not redirected by your `> test.log` at the end of your command.

In order to leave the Python unchanged, you would need to redirect `stderr` as follows - note the `2` denoting `stderr`:

```
/usr/bin/ccube-sensors voltage -m all 2> test.log
```

---

But the better solution, IMHO, is to change your Python to stop abusing `sys.exit()` and use the regular `print()` function, then your original `bash` script will work:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from ccube.apps.ccube_sensors import main
print main()
```

I don't know Python 2.7, but I believe that's how `print()` used to work.

Comment: Solution 1, with the '2>' works perfectly : brilliant. Solution 2 however, display a "0" in addition of the awaited out, so making a ">test.log" you just have this "0" and not the sensors value.

Comment: We don't know that `sys.exit` is being abused; it's fine if `main` actually returns an integer exit code that's *intended* to be passed to `sys.exit`. But it's irrelevant, because `main` apparently writes to standard error, regardless of what it *returns*.

Comment: @chepner Thank you for sharing your insight. I maybe worded it poorly as I haven't seen it used like that before. Not sure what to say as I am unfamiliar with that package. Main thing is that OP can make some progress which seems to be the case.

Comment: I suspect `print main()` is unnecessary, but that is how you would write it if `main` does indeed return a string.